# What is the wiringPi equivalent of wire.requestFrom(...)

Tags: linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c, wiringpi

I am translating an arduino I2C library to run on the raspberry pi, and I need to know how to run the equivalent of `wire.requestFrom(address, size);`. I may be able to implement it myself, but I will need to know what it does. What is the easiest way to achieve this on a raspberry pi?


The library i am translating can be found [here](https://www.piborg.org/ultraborg/examples).

---

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I may be able to implement it myself, but I will need to know what it does.

A good place to answer this question is in [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireRequestFrom) for the Arduino libraries.

The wiringPi library doesn't appear to have an exact analog, but the existing I2C functions are [here](http://wiringpi.com/reference/i2c-library/).